# AWS CLI for SES custom email verification

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, command-line-interface, amazon-ses

Trying to create a custom email verification for SES from the AWS CLI. What mistake am I making?

```
$ aws ses create-custom-verification-email-template --from-email-address "kyle@example.com" --template-subject "confirm" --template-content "confirm-plz" --template-name "custom-template" --success-redirection-url "https://aws.amazon.com/ses/verifysuccess/" --failure-redirection-url "https://aws.amazon.com/ses/verifyfail/"
```

Error message:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the CreateCustomVerificationEmailTemplate operation: The success redirection URL is invalid.

Comment: I tried running this command (with my email address) and I got an error that the email address was not verified. I then created and verified my email address. Then, the above command completed successfully.

Comment: Thanks for trying it for me.  I again tried tonight with the same error.  I moved my SES account out of the sandbox and the same issue.

Comment: I am also running into the same problem. Did you ever solve it?